# How to wait for PostAsync to return?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, uwp, synchronization

I am using Windows.Web.Http.httpclient in a UWP app to make a post call. But I have a use-case where I need to wait for this call to be completed. Is there a way to do that ?.

Code used :

```
httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
httpPromise = httpClient.postAsync(Uri, requestContent);
```

And since Httpclient only provide async methods ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient)), I am not sure if this is even possible.

Environment : Visual studio 2015.

Comment: `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` is a C#/C++ class, why are you looking at JavaScript documentation on async/await for it?

Comment: It is being used in a UWP app (updated the question). Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient apis are available for UWP apps. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http

Comment: @geo: `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` is a Windows Runtime type. There are language projections to consume Windows Runtime types from JavaScript.

Comment: See [Asynchronous patterns in UWP using JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps#asynchronous-patterns-in-uwp-using-javascript).

Comment: Right, you learn something new everyday :)

Comment: If you are using C# you can use ReadAsStringAsync() method to wait and read the result of post as given below -      httpPromise.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Comment: @AmitShishodia, I am using javascript. So I cannot use the above method.

Answer (score 0):

```
httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
var result = await httpClient.postAsync(Uri, requestContent);
```

> you need to use **await** in order to wait for a async call to complete.

Comment: I tried await but it is not working. May be because await can only be used inside an async function (as mentioned here :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Moreover I don't see 'await' under the async representations for javascript at :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps#asynchronous-programming-in-the-uwp .

Comment: yes await can only be used inside async functions, u need to make ur function async in which you are using await.